# Access std class object

Tags: php, stdclass

I've got an object:

`var_dump($f);`

```
object(stdClass)[31]
  public 'id_repertoire' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'nom_file' => string 'chrysanthemum.jpg' (length=17)
  public 'nom_repertoire' => null
```

I need to acess the items, but I can't do it and I can't understand why.

I tried all of these but nothing works. I thought the first line should be working....

```
$id_repertoire = $f[0]->id_repertoire;
$id_repertoire = $f->id_repertoire;
$id_repertoire = $f['id_repertoire'];
```

Thanks for your ideas.

EDIT: Here is the object

```
$sql->query("SELECT avmedias__file.id_repertoire,nom_file,nom_repertoire FROM avmedias__file LEFT JOIN avmedias__repertoire ON avmedias__repertoire.id_repertoire=avmedias__file.id_repertoire WHERE id_file='".(int) $id_file."'");
$f = $sql->fetchO();
```

Comment: the middle one should work

Comment: Strange, normaly you can access with `$f->id_repertoire;`. Do you get an error ?

Comment: What do you get in that `$id_repertoire` anyway?

Comment: Or cast as an array. `$array = (array) $f;`

Comment: can you show how you create the object (looks like database result)?

Comment: The strange thing is, I have the data stored when I do `$f->id_repertoire` but even if the data is stored I got an error: `( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Is this in a loop? Sounds like $f is not an stdClass when that happens. find out why

Comment: Ok so show us how d you create your object

Comment: I edited the fist message

Comment: If `var_dump` shows you __object__, then `$f->id_repertoire` __must__ work. So you show us something that is not your real code.

Comment: @u_mulder you may have miss read. It stores the data but I'm still getting an error. And of course it's the real code...

Comment: Can you try to use `fetchObject()`instead of `fetch()`?

Comment: Fiddle https://3v4l.org/mdPBd

Comment: @Flyzzx fetchO is an alias to this `function fetchO()
    {
        return mysql_fetch_object($this->result);
    }`

Answer (score -2):

First of all convert object to array using this command

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($f), True);
```

and access using

```
$array[0]['id_repertoire']
```

Comment: i think it will help you.

Comment: man before click on down button try to discuss with peoples who are actually trying to solve your problem.

Comment: What is the point in making two calls to json encode and decode? It's completely unnecessary https://3v4l.org/2G5iu

Comment: I think he doesn't downvoted your answer. Everyone here can downvote answers. Try to improve your answer and explain why your solution work and why `$f->id_repertoire` doesn't work.